# ASP.Net : Need to run javascript on update panel load completed

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I need to run a javascript function when the update panel is loaded completely(I want to scroll), and not on initial page load.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

This is the way to get the end Event after the update.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = Sys.Application;
  app.add_init(ApplicationInit);

  function ApplicationInit(sender) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
    {
        prm.add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded);
    }
  }

  function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
    //Do something
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX then the only way i have found yet to give an alert to a user on return to the Asynchronous post back is to add an “end request” handler to the PageRequestManager.

In this way you can tell the request manager to run a javascript function on returning from a Asynchronous post back event of AJAX.

Code for doing this is :

```
function load()

{
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
```

where “EndRequestHandler” will be the name of your javascript function you want to call.
Call the above function in Onload event of  tag:

```
<body onload=”load()”>

function EndRequestHandler()

{

          alert(“You record has been saved successfully”);

}
```

Now If you want to give a different message based on your logic in server side code (code behind) then you can use a server side Hidden Field:

```
<input id=”hdnValue” type=”hidden” runat=”server”  value=”" />
```

Set its value in server side code on Asychronous Post Back:

Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateSample.Click

```
    If condition Then

    hdnValue.value = “do this”

    Else     

    hdnValue.value = “do that” 

    End If 

End Sub
```

Now you can check the value of this Hidden Field in your Client Side EndRequestHandler function and give a different alert to user based on its value:

```
function EndRequestHandler()
{
     if (document.getElementById(‘<%= hdnValue.ClientID %>’).value == “do this”)

     { 
          alert(“You record has been saved successfully”);
     } 
     else
     {
          alert(“There is an error”);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code with if jquery is used

This is to show saved message and hide that message after 5 seconds after update panel is updated

```
function pageLoad() {
            window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        }
        function EndRequestHandler()
        {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var label = window.$get('<%= lblMsg.ClientID%>');
                if (label != null) { label.style.display = 'none'; }
            }, 5000);
        }
```