# jquery accordion not re-initiating after an asp.Net postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, postback, accordion

I'm firing up a jquery accordion with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#accordion').accordion();
});
```

Problem is this is an .asp.NET application and if the page fires a postback is destroys the accordion. How do I re-initiate the accordion upon postback?

Sorry I'm not an expert on asp.NET, and also sorry I can't give you a link to the example, this is because it's a password protected application.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use update panel in your project?

Comment: Yes it does, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to re-initlaize the accordion after the post back with the UpdatePanel functions as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
   // on page ready first init of your accordion
   $('#accordion').accordion();
});


function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
     // after the UpdatePanel finish the render from ajax call
     //  and the DOM is ready, re-initilize the accordion
     $('#accordion').accordion();
}
</script>
```

Relative:
[Asp.Net UpdatePanel in Gridview Jquery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741)
[ASP.Net : Need to run javascript on update panel load completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985937/asp-net-need-to-run-javascript-on-update-panel-load-completed/2987484#2987484)
[How do you get client-side script to execute on an ASP.NET postback? (from an UpdatePanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257973/how-do-you-get-client-side-script-to-execute-on-an-asp-net-postback-from-an-up/3258167#3258167)

Comment: Thanks. I took this option in the end, and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitAccordion);
function InitAccordion(){       
   $('#accordion').accordion();}
```

This will work for postback and asyncpostback
Raised after all content on the page is refreshed as a result of either a synchronous or an asynchronous postback.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523(v=vs.100).aspx