# CSS disappearing in updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

i have this problem, i putted my whole page in the update panel , i have several `ASP:Pannel`
with `Visible="false"` attribute.

one of them containing `asp:RadioButtonList` With `Yes,No`

at the `Page_Load()` one of them get visible to the user with the radio button list.
so when he press `Yess`, another panel get visible to him .

the problem is i have a panel containing  `asp:DropDownList` with

`CssClass="span6 chzn-select">`

so when this panel get visible the `DropDownList` `css` disappear !.
i know that there is a problem with the update panel post back , but i don't know how to solve this .
also the `DropDownList` get the style from JQuery file called chosen but i don't have any script at any page , i just put the css class and it have it's style.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `yourUpdatePanel.Update();`

Answer (score 0):

Modifications made to elements (like adding styles) made by javascript don't persist through postbacks, even partial postbacks. All javascript initialization needs to be redone after postback.

Here is a javascript snippet that adds a callback for completion of a partial postback. You can use this to set up your UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    }
</script>
```

Snippet taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985937/asp-net-need-to-run-javascript-on-update-panel-load-completed).

Comment: what should  put here ?
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    }

Comment: not working :( i tried this 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        $('#drpClients').addClass('span6 chzn-select');
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Plugins like Chosen are more than just CSS. They uses JavaScript to find select elements with that class and augment/replace them with different markup that can be styled nicely.

It's not that your CSS is being lost when the UpdatePanel refreshes, but that the Chosen JavaScript isn't running to find and re-enhance those normal `<select>` elements with the Chosen class on them.

You should be able to re-initialize them with this code:

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
```

You could run that on page load and after every UpdatePanel refresh by putting it in [the pageLoad() function that ASP.NET calls by convention](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/):

```
function pageLoad() {
  $('.chzn-select').chosen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same page add the following js function (not inside documentready)

```
<script>
function pageLoad() {
 $('#drpClients').addClass('span6 chzn-select');
}
</script>
```